# youtubeextractor getting different resolutions

Tags: c#

If anyone is familiar with using youtubeextractor, I am trying to do the following.  I am using this example posted on the site for the library.

```
string link = "youtube link";

IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link);

VideoInfo video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);
```

This code only looks for a specific resolution, what if that resolution doesn't exist?

If anyone has an example of looking for a resolution of lets say 1080, if 1080 doesn't exist then we look for 720, otherwise grab a 420 resolution, in this priority order: `1080 -> 720 -> 480`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(txtUrl.Text);
foreach (var vid in videos) {
    if (vid.Resolution > maxRez)
        maxRez = vid.Resolution;
}
cboRezolution.Text = maxRez.ToString();
VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(maxRez));
lblStatus.Text = video.Title;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VideoInfo video = videoInfos.OrderByDescending(info=>info.Resolution)
                  .First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4)
```

This will return the .MP4 video with best resolution.

If you are interested in only some resolutions then you can do it as

```
var allowedResolutions = new List<int>() { 1080, 720, 480, 360 };

VideoInfo video = videoInfos.OrderByDescending(info=>info.Resolution)
                  .Where(info => allowedResolutions.Contains(info.Resolution))
                  .First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4)
```

Comment: You kinda lost me on this response.  How is OrderByDescending() looking for specific resolutions?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @sledgehammer It tries to find the max resolution whichever is available

Comment: Lets say I have the resolution stored in an ini file and I want to

Comment: Lets say, you are smart enough to read a file, put the desired res to *allowedResolutions* and use above code....

Comment: Just noticed your response above.  I really need to brush up on this library but I cant find any docs on it.  I guess I was looking for something like if 1080 doesnt exist then look for 720, if that doesnt exist then look for 480.  Looking at what you posted looks just like sql.  I do appreciate your help on this.

Comment: actually it's LINQ, that's why it looks like SQL (guess you mean the Where and First terms), it's been made to query data sources

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<VideoInfo> GetVideoInfos(YoutubeModel model)
{
    int xx;
    IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(model.Link);

        int[] arr = new int[3] { 360, 720, 1080 };
        for (xx = 0; xx < 3; xx++)
        {
            try 
            {
                VideoInfo video = videoInfos
                                   .First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == arr[xx]);
            }
            catch (Exception st)
            {

            }
        }
    return videoInfos;
}

//Returns VideoInfo object (Only for video model)
public static VideoInfo GetVideoInfo(YoutubeVideoModel videoModel)
{
    //Select the first .mp4 video with 360p resolution
    VideoInfo video = videoModel.VideoInfo.First();
    return video;
}
```